# How can I get LibreOffice to 'number' footnotes in the order *, †, ‡,  §  etc.?

Tags: libreoffice, numbering, libreoffice-writer, footnote

With LaTeX, I can do:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[symbol*]{footmisc}

\begin{document}
One\footnote{f1} Two \footnote{f2} Three \footnote{f3} Four \footnote{f4} 
\end{document}
```

And get *, †, ‡, § ...  as consecutive footnote markers. MS-Word has this feature too - an alternative footnote numbering scheme. How can I achieve the same with LibreOffice?

PS - Shouldn't the OpenOffice and LibreOffice tags be merged?

Comment: LibreOffice is a fork from OpenOffice, so they are 2 separate softwares and their tags shouldn't be merged imho.

Comment: @m4573r: OpenOffice-tagged questions are probably about both, and LibreOffice seems to be the more popular. But, well, never mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On advice from people at the LibreOffice forum, I filed this:

https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=55436

So, it's now a known and unresolved bug.